# MySQL "group by" maintaining the sorting of data

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a problem removing duplicates in a select query, while still considering the order of the rows.
I have the following example data:

```
myDate      myValue
---------------------------
2014-01-01  100
2014-01-02  100
2014-01-03  200
2014-01-04  100
2014-01-05  100
2014-01-06  100
2014-01-07  300
```

I need a query able to remove duplicates which come on following dates. Thereby, producing the following result, note that the value 100 is returned more than once in the result, which is not the case for my current query.

```
myDate      myValue
---------------------------
2014-01-01  100
2014-01-03  200
2014-01-04  100
2014-01-07  300
```

What I have so far which does not work is:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT myDate, myValue
   FROM testtable
   ORDER BY myDate
) AS t_temp GROUP BY myValue;
```

Any ideas on how I could improve the query to produce the desired result?

Comment: Does your `myDate` column contains continuous dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not verified this, but I think this will give you what you're looking for. The inner query grabs each row, where the current value does not match the previous one. It uses `@previous` to keep track of previous row. Otherwise, it generates a `NULL` row. And finally, the outer query eliminates the `NULL` rows.

For example, when it looks at the first row, it sees that `myValue` doesn't match `@previous`, because it is empty, and it grabs the whole row. When it looks at the second row, it sees that `myValue` equals `@previous`, so in this case, it generates NULLs. When it looks at the third row, it sees that `myValue` does not equal `100`, so it grabs the whole row. And it does this to the end. Then the outer query eliminates all the `NULL` rows.

```
SET @previous := '';

SELECT
    myDate,
    myValue
FROM (
    SELECT
        IF( myValue != @previous, myDate, NULL ) AS myDate,
        IF( myValue != @previous, myValue, NULL ) AS myValue,
        @previous := myValue
    FROM testtable
) temp
WHERE myDate IS NOT NULL;
```

This can also be written as follows:

```
SELECT
    myDate,
    myValue
FROM (
    SELECT
        IF( myValue != @previous, myDate, NULL ) AS myDate,
        IF( myValue != @previous, myValue, NULL ) AS myValue,
        @previous := myValue
    FROM my_table
       , (SELECT @previous := '') val
   ORDER
      BY myDate
) temp
WHERE myDate IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I need. However, the first line comes out with an error, but the rest works perfectly without it.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include SET in the first line. Glad I could help.

Comment: Whoa, did not realize other people can edit my answer; not cool.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you would use LAG or LEAD to look into the previous or next record, but MySQL doesn't support them.

So provided there is an entry for every day, you can just select the day before and compare with the current value:

```
select 
  mytable.mydate, 
  mytable.myvalue
from mytable 
left outer join mytable prev on adddate(prev.mydate, interval 1 day) = mytable.mydate
where prev.myvalue is null or prev.myvalue != mytable.myvalue
order by mydate;
```

If there are gaps however, you would have to select all earlier records and find the minimum date within to get the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way (note; my data set is slightly different from yours)...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
(myDate      DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,myValue INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('2014-01-01',100),
('2014-01-02',100),
('2014-01-03',200),
('2014-01-04',100),
('2014-01-07',100),
('2014-01-08',100),
('2014-01-09',300);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+------------+---------+
| myDate     | myValue |
+------------+---------+
| 2014-01-01 |     100 |
| 2014-01-02 |     100 |
| 2014-01-03 |     200 |
| 2014-01-04 |     100 |
| 2014-01-07 |     100 |
| 2014-01-08 |     100 |
| 2014-01-09 |     300 |
+------------+---------+

SELECT a.myDate 
     , a.myValue
  FROM (SELECT x.*, COUNT(*) rank FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.myDate <= x.myDate GROUP BY x.myDate) a
  LEFT 
  JOIN (SELECT x.*, COUNT(*) rank FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.myDate <= x.myDate GROUP BY x.myDate) b 
    ON b.myValue = a.myValue
   AND b.rank = a.rank - 1
  LEFT 
  JOIN (SELECT x.*, COUNT(*) rank FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.myDate <= x.myDate GROUP BY x.myDate) c 
    ON c.myValue = a.myValue
   AND c.rank >= a.rank
  LEFT 
  JOIN (SELECT x.*, COUNT(*) rank FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.myDate <= x.myDate GROUP BY x.myDate) d 
    ON d.myValue = a.myValue
   AND d.rank = c.rank + 1 
 WHERE b.rank IS NULL 
   AND c.rank IS NOT NULL
   AND d.rank IS NULL
 GROUP 
    BY a.rank;

+------------+---------+
| myDate     | myValue |
+------------+---------+
| 2014-01-01 |     100 |
| 2014-01-03 |     200 |
| 2014-01-04 |     100 |
| 2014-01-09 |     300 |
+------------+---------+
```

If the days really are sequential, without gaps, then this can be simplified.

Comment: This seems to be doing what I want, but it is rather complicated, especially when the original table (my_table) is generated from another complicated query, combining three different tables. Thank you very much for the effort. However, I will choose walterquez answer as the accepted one as it is pretty simple and also does what I need.

Answer (score -2):

Use the `min()` aggregate function so you always get the lowest date for each `myValue` grouping:

```
SELECT MIN(myDate), myValue
FROM testtable
GROUP BY myValue
ORDER BY myValue
```

Comment: but `order by MIN(myDate)` ;) (or with an alias)

Comment: By the way, it's not what's asked, I think. There's a point on `duplicates which come on following dates.` So the rank is important.

Comment: @RagingBull: actually, no it won't. totally missed the "dupes on following dates" bit. This won't work at all for that. standard SQL has no concept of "next" or "previous" rows, really.

Comment: Perhaps not, but it understands "following dates"